# Cannot access property added via prototype using "this," in Javascript

Tags: javascript, class

I'm building a class that is shared between a game engine and an editor. There are some properties and methods I want to be defined in the editor, but not the engine so I wrote the following code

```
class Asset{
    constructor(){
        this.prop1 = 1;
    }
}

if (window.IS_EDITOR){
    Asset.prototype.editorProp = 2;
}

class Room extends Asset{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.prop2 = 3;

        console.log(this)
        //expected:   {prop1: 1, prop2: 3, editorProp: 2}
        //what I get: {pro1: 1, prop2: 3}
    }
}
```

I'm basically just trying to conditionally add another property to the constructor, but I'm confused why the `editorProp` isn't showing up when I access `this`.

Comment: Are you certain window.IS_EDITOR is resolving to true?

Comment: Well, `editorProp` is on the prototype, as you’ve specified. You’re logging the instance instead. Just go through the prototype chain in your console and you’ll find this property.

Comment: Once you mutate the Asset's prototype, it will stay mutated in both the game engine and editor environment

Comment: Question about your approach: if you're using class notation, _why_  are you directly accessing the prototype instead of having a static class property setter `static setEditorProp(value) { this.editorProp = value; }` (where `this` in static context is the class itself) and a getter `get editorProp() { return Asset.editorProp; }`?

Comment: Sorry, I should have clarified: This is a simplified version to illustrate the issue. There are currently about 10 different props and methods that I would like to only be defined in one use case or the other

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I'm confused why the `editorProp` isn't showing up when I access `this`.

Because it's on the prototype of your object, just like the `.constructor`, and won't be printed by default when you `console.log` it. You'll find it if you expand the prototype, or if you `console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(this))`. You still can access it as `this.editorProp` with the expected value, as it is inherited.

> I'm trying to conditionally add another property to the constructor

If you want to add the property to the instance in the constructor, you should actually do it in the constructor:

```
class Asset {
    constructor() {
        this.prop1 = 1;
        if (window.IS_EDITOR) {
            this.editorProp = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was my original approach, but it seemed redundant to do the check every time an asset was created since `IS_EDITOR` will never change during runtime and editing the prototype seemed cleaner and more efficient. If it isn't possible though then this will do

Comment: Well what do you need the (conditional) `editorProp` property for in the first place?

Comment: And yes, it totally is possible to use the prototype, it works just fine, it's just not visible in `console.log`.

Answer (score 0):

Like pointed out, `console.log` is just logging the object, not what's in the prototype chain.  So doing `console.log(this.editorProp)` will indeed return `2`, as the prototype chain is now been used.

If you want to see the object with the prototype flattened it's pretty easy to do using `in`.  In the example below I've added a simple function called `flat` that does this.

Also worth noting adding methods to a class will make them automatically none enumerable, but if you add a method to the prototype it will be enumerable.  So an example below I've also added a function called `fn` but using `defineProperty` to stop it been enumerable.

```js
window.IS_EDITOR = true;

class Asset{
    constructor(){
        this.prop1 = 1;
    }
}

if (window.IS_EDITOR){
    Asset.prototype.editorProp = 2;
    //adding a function this will will be
    //enumerable, so you might want to use
    //defineProperty here.
    Object.defineProperty(
      Asset.prototype,
      'fn',
      {value: () => {console.log('fn called')}, enumerable: false});
}

class Room extends Asset{
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.prop2 = 3;
        console.log(this.flat());
        this.fn();
        //expected:   {prop1: 1, prop2: 3, editorProp: 2}
        //what I get: {pro1: 1, prop2: 3}
    }
    flat() {
      const ret = {};
      for (const i in this) ret[i] = this[i];
      return ret;
    }
}

new Room();
```